# Dynamically Update DIV information based on CHECKBOX input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list

I am trying to have a list of input checkboxes (which will be generated by PHP at a later time) but for now the content is static. So based off of the input, be able to select an employee, populates my div based on the selection and when unchecking the input, remove that same employee. I also need to be able to select multiple employees, instead of just one. Currently it updates the div with an employee but I cannot remove said employee. I can also only select one employee at a time (need to be able to click as many employees as needed all at once).

Here is what I got:

HTML

```
<div id="employee-list">
</div>

 <div class="small-2 columns bord-right3 check-box">
 <input type="checkbox" class="boxid" value="Joe Smith" name="employees">
 <label class="checkbox-select">Select</label>
</div>
<div class="small-10 columns bord-right3">
  <span class="employee-name">Joe Smith</span>
</div>

<div class="small-2 columns bord-right3 check-box">
 <input type="checkbox" class="boxid" value="John Smith" name="employees">
 <label class="checkbox-select">Select</label>
</div>
<div class="small-10 columns bord-right3">
  <span class="employee-name">John Smith</span>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('input[name="employees"]').change(function () {

 var inputVal = $('input[name="employees"]:checked').map(function () {
    return this.value;
}).get();
console.log(inputVal);

if ($(this).prop('checked')) {  //which checkbox was checked

    if ($(this).val() == inputVal ) { 
        $("#employee-list").append('<span class="employee-name2_1"><a href="#" class="item">X</a> ' + inputVal + '</span>');
    }

} else {
    $('.li_'+$(this).val()).remove();
    console.log('item removed');
}

});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Please let me know if I have missed anything.

Comment: and what is the problem? is it not working ?

Comment: @TiagoFabre It does not remove said item from the div, it console logs it fine and shows it is removed but not from the actual div. Also does not allow me to select multiple people to update the div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the goal correctly some of your code inside the change listener was unnecessary.  You don't have to use `map` to get the value of the checkbox, `$(this).val()` is sufficient.  From there a single if/else can add or remove the information as necessary.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w9oowjv2/)

```
$('input[name="employees"]').change(function () {
  var inputVal = $(this).val();
  var className = inputVal.replace(/ /g, '_');

  if ($(this).prop('checked')) {  //which checkbox was checked
    $("#employee-list").append('<span class="span_' + className + '"><a href="#" class="item">X</a> ' + inputVal + '</span>');
  } else {
    $('.span_'+className).remove();
    console.log('item removed');
  }
});
```

Comment: this was exactly what I was trying to achieve. I have updated my question with the proper div id (it was the first div but with the wrong id). Thank you! This was most helpful. Could you explain what the ' (/ /g, '_')' portion you have is doing? I would like to understand what is going on there. Thank you once again.

Comment: That just replaces any spaces in the persons name with an underscore so I can use that as a class name later on to remove the span. The `/ /` matches a space and the `g` means "global" (all spaces).  `'_'` is what the spaces found should be replaced with (an underscore).  If I tried to use the persons name with spaces as a class name each name would be its own class.

Comment: Thank you for the details. Again appreciate your response but unfortunately due to lack of reputation I cannot upvote your response but this was a solution to my question. Most helpful.